# Absolute path for jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to cut the source sting to what it is as on different pages it changes. This is the jquery ui autocomplete code

```
 $().ready(function() {

 $("#abc").autocomplete({
    source: "atc/atcomp.php",
    minLength: 3,
    html: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").css({'z-index': '1000'});
    }
 });

}
```

The source source: `atc/atcomp.php` keeps on changing when I move to a different page like it becomes source: `category/atc/atcomp.php` instead of being the same so the autocomplete does not work on that page is there a solution to the or is there a way to make the path absolute?

Answer (score 1):

Same as any link/src/reference. Prefix it with a `/` to denote the root:

```
$("#abc").autocomplete({
    source: "/atc/atcomp.php",
    minLength: 3,
    html: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").css({'z-index': '1000'});
    }
 });
```

Comment: Not working after the / prefix... Any other solution ? Its giving a 404 not found error in the chrome browser tools network tab

Comment: keeping the `atcomp.php` file on the root is also not working with or without a `/` on other pages